# How to generate n+1 long list, filled with 0s?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How to generate n+1 long list, filled with 0s? is there something that looks like `list=[0]+(n+1)?`

Comment: Don't assign list as a variable, you'll lose the builtin list constructor.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
[0] * (n+1) # using the * operator
```

For example:

```
n = 4
lst = [0] * (n+1)
lst
=> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Read more about the correct usage of the multiplication operator on lists, [here](http://helloacm.com/multiplication-operator-in-python/) in a blog post.

Answer (score 7):

```
lst = [0] * (n+1)
```

(don't use "list" as a variable name, it hides the `list()` function)